# Force to SSL maintaining the URL

Tags: apache

I don't have much experience with VHOST and SSL, I tried lot of possibilities but none of them is working.

I have a website with 2 folders:

www.example.com/userpage
www.example.com/adminpage

If I go to www.example.com, my loginsystem automatically redirect to www.example.com/userpage.
If I want to go to the admin section, I have to write manually www.example.com/adminpage.

Now I switched to SSL, and everything is working if I type https://....
But I cannot understand how to force the redirect from http to https.

I wrote this in my apache vhost file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
ServerName example.com

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteCond ${HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

But it's not working.
How can I manage it?

If I write www.example.com/adminpage it have to redirect me to https://www.example.com/adminpage.

Actually it should work for every subfolder, if for example I send an email to a user saying "hey user, please check your account www.example.com/user/check_account.php?userid=14125114
it have to then redirect it to automatically:
https://www.example.com/user/check_account.php?userid=14125114

so it should work for every page and every subfolder.
Thank you for your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Should be quite simple. Replace this block:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteCond ${HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

With this:

```
 Redirect permanent "/" "https://example.com/"
```

Comment: Thank you! With this solution it works partially, if I go to www.example.com/admin it redirects me to https://www.example.comadmin (withouth slash)

Comment: ok, post updated. If still fails try with a private browser window.